# Getting over Mathematica Bar Chart Limitations….

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create a pareto chart for some non technical folks and having the hardest time formatting it correctly…

Here’s my sample code:

```
(*Some dynamically generated data *)

mydata = {0.9436, 2.20725333345, 2.1402, 1.8729, 4.9436, 0.4819};
mylabels = {"l1", "l2", "l3", "l4", "some really long label", "another really long label", "l7"};

(*lets riffle and sort the data *)

a =  Sort[ Partition[Riffle[mylabels, mydata], 2], #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] & ];

BarChart[a , BarOrigin -> Left, BarSpacing -> -1, LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, After] &), Axes -> None, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, FrameLabel -> "Some Title", GridLines -> None, AspectRatio -> 0.3, ImageSize -> Full, ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

A few questions:

- What is the best way to truncate to 2 digits in the labels, I tried using `NumberForm` in the Sort function but doesn’t work since Numberform is a wrapper.
- Labeling works reasonably well  when labels are short but I seem to run into placement issues with long labels… Any ideas on better ways to handle this?
- Frame produced by Mathematica seems to overlap with the labels…

Any suggestions gladly appreciated!

Comment: You are aware of the [ParetoPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/StatisticalPlots/ref/ParetoPlot.html) function?

Comment: Yes… same issues apply to Pareto as well.. I thought asking a question about BarCharts may garner more responses….

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach.

```
mydata = N[Round[{0.9436, 2.20725333345, 2.1402, 1.8729, 4.9436, 0.4819}*100]/100];
```

This will make the data appear with only 2 decimal places of accuracy. If you are willing to rearrange things a bit, it's pretty easy to remove the overlap...

```
BarChart[Labeled[#2, #1, Before] & @@@ a, BarSpacing -> 0, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, After] &), BarOrigin -> Left, 
  PlotLabel -> "Some Title"]
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: That works…  why doesn’t N[mydata,2] work?

Comment: Because the numbers you have are floating point... this would work if the argument were rational. For example, if you had expressed mydata as {47/50, 221/100, 107/50, 187/100, 247/50, 12/25}, then N[mydata,{4,3}] would do what you want.

Comment: Makes sense… thanks