# Labelling of multiple BarChart elements with "Stacked" layout

Tags: plotting, labeling

I am trying to create a stacked `BarChart` where each `BarChart` has different `ChartLabels`. Consider the following example:

```
BarChart[{{5, 6, 7, 5, 7}, {8, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"One", "Two"}, Above], 
   Placed[{5, 6, 7, 5, 7}, Center]}]
```

> [image]

But what I would like to have is separate labels for the segments in the two chart elements. The following image illustrates this:

> [image]

I can't figure out how to do that using `ChartLabels`. When I try providing multiple lists for the chart labels it doesn't work.

Comment: Here it is `BarChart[{{5, 6, 7, 5, 7}, {8, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &), ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Label both sides in BarChart](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17624/label-both-sides-in-barchart)

Comment: Not sure if it is a dupe, have a look if it helps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22466/1356) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17624/label-both-sides-in-barchart) give the answer by using [LabelingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LabelingFunction.html). Thus you can use

```
BarChart[{{5, 6, 7, 5, 7}, {8, 5, 6, 7, 8}}, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#1, Center] &), 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

And have:

> [image: Tada!]